# No output from shutdown when used within a shell script

Tags: linux, shell-script, centos

I have the following in a shell script

```
fulloutput="<pre>$(df -h /;sudo shutdown -r +1 )</pre>"
```

Later in the script I echo this variable (it's piped to sendmail but that's irrelevant here) but I only get the output from the df command, not the shutdown.

I have tried without `sudo` and I have tried separating the commands like follows...

```
fulloutput="<pre>$(df -h /) $(sudo shutdown -r +1 )</pre>"
```

But still only get the output from the `df` command.

It's not a big issue, but it would be nice to get the output from `shutdown` as an indicator that that part of my script has executed succesfully.

Comment: @steeldriver Is it possible to redirect it to stdout?  I tried ">&1" after the shutdown command but that didn't work.

Comment: That worked.   If you would like to post that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command substitution captures `stdout`; the shutdown message is likely written to `stderr`.

To redirect `stderr` to `stdout` so that it is captured as well, add `2>&1` i.e.

```
$(df -h /; sudo shutdown -r +1 2>&1)
```